# Railo coldfusion cfdiv error

Tags: coldfusion, railo

I just installed Railo 3 latest version on my Win7 PC. I've added a couple test variables using cfset and those output fine so i know Railo is running.

I added a simple cfdiv tag with no parameters set and when i run the page i get an error.

Then i tried another cfdiv setting each parameter that are marked as optional and i've gotten the error to disappear.

I have always used Adobe Coldfusion and I'm already starting to feel like the end result is going to be more predictable using Adobe Coldfusion.  What do others think about some of the knock Coldfusion implementations like Railo and OpenBD?

Comment: "What do others think..." is explicitly listed in the [FAQ] as the kind of question to ***not*** ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CFDiv is an extension for the engine. So it is added as a CFC based custom tag. If there is anything wrong with it you could submit a patch for it since it is all written in CFML. 
Although it is nice to have all tha AJAX tags I would always recommend using a javascript framework like JQuery or ExtJS.

Gert

Comment: Yeah, it was weird. The problem was when i would add a cfdiv tag to my page with any of its parameters i would get a CF error.  So, I'm not able to use CFDIV at all at the moment in my page.  I was just trying out Railo to see if it was something worth getting into VS sticking with Adobe Coldfusion, but I am thinking that the Adobe Coldfusion is just better, more stable.  Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with any of them IMHO. Use whatever works best for you. =) That's the beauty of choice!